# How to prevent circular dependency in neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am newbie to Neo4j and trying to use this to save some relationships between the nodes which would prevent circular loop.

I have created a application where user can have some triggers run when some type of CRUD operation occurs on a node. In the below diagram, For example: If a insert happens on employee then insert in a department. So I have node of label `:collection` and relation between them using `[:collection_rel]` with some properties.

I have a scenario where I need to prevent creating a relationship, if that relationship is created, then that will cause circular dependency. This is shown in red color with "x". So, if we try to add a relation between location and employee with a property `"OnInsert-ThenInsert"` or `"OnUpdate-ThenUpdate"`, this would cause a infinite loop. So for this kind of scenarios, we need to prevent adding the relation.

How can this be achieved? Is this doable in Neo4j?

SAMPLE DATA:

```
CREATE (n:Collection { collection_name: "employee" }), (n1:Collection { collection_name: "department" }), (n2:Collection { collection_name: "category" }), (n3:Collection { collection_name: "location" }) RETURN n,n1,n2,n3

MATCH (a:Collection { collection_name: "employee" }), (b:Collection { collection_name: "department" })
CREATE (a)-[r:collection_rel {type: "CRUD", details: "OnUpdate-ThenUpdate"}]->(b)

MATCH (a:Collection { collection_name: "employee" }), (b:Collection { collection_name: "department"})
CREATE (a)-[r:collection_rel {type: "CRUD", details: "OnDelete-ThenInsert"}]->(b)

MATCH (a:Collection { collection_name: "employee" }), (b:Collection { collection_name: "department" })
CREATE (a)-[r:collection_rel {type: "CRUD", details: "OnInsert-ThenInsert"}]->(b)

MATCH (a:Collection { collection_name: "department" }), (b:Collection { collection_name: "category" })
CREATE (a)-[r:collection_rel {type: "CRUD", details: "OnUpdate-ThenUpdate"}]->(b)

MATCH (a:Collection { collection_name: "department" }), (b:Collection { collection_name: "location" })
CREATE (a)-[r:collection_rel {type: "CRUD", details: "OnInsert-ThenInsert"}]->(b)

MATCH (a:Collection { collection_name: "category" }), (b:Collection { collection_name: "location" })
CREATE (a)-[r:collection_rel {type: "CRUD", details: "OnUpdate-ThenUpdate"}]->(b)
```

[image: nodes]

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear... Try providing more details. Share the query that you are facing with an "infinite loop"... Maybe the expected result. Thanks.

Comment: But I suppose that you are trying to prevent the relationship creation between the employee and location nodes at the persistence layer (neo4j). In this case I think the best place to handle this rule is in the application layer, since your are dealing with a business rule.

Comment: @BrunoPeres  I would like to do this in Application layer depending on the result from neo4j. In the above example, for a Business Rule when executed for location while inserting a recording then this would happen

Comment: (location)-[r:collection_rel {type: "CRUD", details: "OnInsert-ThenInsert"}]->(employee) then triggers
(employee)-[r:collection_rel {type: "CRUD", details: "OnInsert-ThenInsert"}]->(department) then triggers
(department)-[r:collection_rel {type: "CRUD", details: "OnInsert-ThenInsert"}]->(location) then triggers


In the above scenario, this never ends and fallsback to infinite loop